# Running TrueNAS-12.0-U8.1, alert says that certificate "freenas_default" has expired

Tags: certificate, truenas

TrueNAS says that the "freenas_default" certificate has expired.

Apparently due to this expiration, I am unable to do some things with the network, including updating software.  There is precious little help that I can find, and I've yet to run across any article that attempts to solve the problem.  A search for Certificates in the manual did not reveal a way to circumvent this problem.

I ran freenas for years (versions 9, 11) without issue.  Now, three months after installing TrueNAS I have this problem.

Looking in the GUI for TrueNAS, there is a Certificates section.  Exactly one certificate is listed:

```
freenas_default
external
/C=US/O=iXsystems/CN=lo
Valid 2020-04-15 to 2022-07-19
```

There is an option to Add a certificate, which presents a form with a lot of questions, some of which I am not sure how to answer.  The options available for the existing certificate are: View, Export Certificate, Export Private Key, Delete.  I'd hoped to see RENEW there but alas.

What should I try in order to get past this?

Update: When trying to create a new certificate as suggested by @Ramhound in the comments, I am unable to satisfy the Signing Certificate Authority requirement.  See images.

[image: Empty Dropdown list]

[image: Result of selecting -- item from dropdown]

Comment: [This](https://www.truenas.com/docs/core/coretutorials/systemconfiguration/creatingcasandcertificates/creatingcertificates/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20TrueNAS%20comes%20equipped%20with%20an%20internal%2C,name%20for%20the%20certificate%2C%20then%20choose%20the%20Type.) should help

Comment: [The FreeNas certificate is intended](https://www.reddit.com/r/truenas/comments/wdyjvy/certificate_freenas_default_is_expiring/) but it’s also just a default TLS certificate which should be replaced by your own, or just ignore the certificate error, since expired self signed certificates are secure and trusted vs revoked certificates.

Comment: My suggestion, upgrade to TrueNAS 13.0-U1.1, and the expired default certificate issue likely will be resolved

Comment: Which fields in the form confuse you?

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound.  Regarding the upgrade comment, I'm more inclined to understand and resolve the problem than to just make it go away.  On the first comment: maybe it's unrelated, but now when I try 'sudo apt update' in a virtual machine on this system, I get an error about no valid certificates found(?).  Don't believe I've ever seen that before, and now after restart I cannot connect to the virtual machine either by ssh, GUI Serial or VNC.  As I say, maybe unreleated but now I'm lost.

Comment: @RomeoNinov for example, Signing certificate authority, whose help says: Select a previously imported or created CA.  There are no items in the dropdown to choose, so I cannot create one... and from where would I import one?  Or how about "Organizational Unit," whose very unhelpful "help" says, "Organizational unit of the entity?"

Comment: @Dennis - The page I linked to explains how to create and import the new self signed certificate. Your inability to SSH is could be connected to the expiration of the certificate but also unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound - I didn't see the "this should help" comment until today.  I have gone through those steps with one exception.  The "Signing Certificate Authority" is a required field with dropdown selection.  That dropdown has no items in it (other than the --, which is equivalent to "no entry" and therefore doesn't work).  Suggestions?  (I added images to show the problem)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same condition on my TrueNAS 12.0 setup.  What I did to fix it is a simple three step process.

First, you create your own internal CA.  **System > CAs > Add**.  Just give it a name, mark it as type *Internal*, complete the required lines of the Certificate Subject like with any other self-signed cert.  Then submit.

This allows you to complete step two.  **System > Certificates**.  This part is almost identical to step one, except that now you have "Signing Certificate Authority" you can choose when you make the new certificate here.  Once you submit, then you have to tell TrueNAS which cert to use for HTTPS.

Go to **System > General** and very first option is "*GUI SSL Certificate*".  Select your newly created cert.  It will ask if you want to restart the web service (yes).  Then repoint your browser, accept the self signed cert and you are good to go.

Hope it helps!